# Multiple Dynamic Time Event Listener

Tags: java, android, event-listener

This solution for time event listeners is awesome:
[Time Event Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502441/time-event-listener)

Here's a code sample:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Intent activate = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
AlarmManager alarms ;
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, activate, 0);
alarms = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
alarms.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
```

How can I make many of these dynamically? I have a for loop with `int i` containing all hours that the user wants to set alarms to. I thought of creating dynamic instances of Calendar (cal+i), but we don't have it in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, the solution was by repeating the code and using `i` as a request code in the pendingIntent like this :

```
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, i, activate, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the calendar values and then use `cal.getTimeInMillis()`. You dont need several instances of Calendar with that. The result is a primitive, not an object.

Ref:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis()

Answer (score 0):

Juan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31462769/913286) is right, you may use a single calendar to compute many timestamps and then loop through them and schedule the alarms. The following code uses an array to keep track of the timestamps and shows the approach more concretely:

```
long[] times = new long[3];
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
times[0] = cal.getTimeInMillis();  // timestamp of now
cal.add(HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
times[1] = cal.getTimeInMillis();  // in one hour
cal.add(MINUTES, 30);
times[2] = cal.getTimeInMillis();  // in one and a half hour

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, activate, 0);
for (long time : times) {        
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
}
```